# LWC @Wire - Apex method is not a known adapter

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm fairly new to LWCs and Apex and am working on a requirement to build an LWC data table that can be accessed from a custom app page.

However, I'm running into the following error when trying to deploy into my scratch org:

```
LWC1503: "getUncategorizedDocuments" from "@Salesforce/apex/OnboardingReviewDocController1.getUncategorizedDocuments" is not a known adapter. (45:11)
```

HTML:

```
<template>

   <!------Header------->
    <div class="slds-tabs_card">
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-page-header__row">
                <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                    <div class="slds-media">
                        <div class="slds-media__figure">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity">
                                 <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:recipe" alternative-text="recipe" title="recipe"></lightning-icon>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-media__body">
                            <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                                <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                    <h1>
                                        <span>Uncategorized Onboarding Application Documents</span>
                                        <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Recently Viewed"></span>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <br/>
    <!------/Header------->
    
    <lightning-card title="Uncategorized Onboarding Application Documents" icon-name="standard:document">
       <template if:true={onbAppDocs.data}>
           <lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
                                data={onbAppDocs.data} 
                                columns={columns} 
                                onsave={handleSave}
                                draft-values={DraftValues} 
                                hide-checkbox-column 
                                show-row-number-column>
           </lightning-datatable>
       </template>
       <template if:true={onbAppDocs.error}>
                <!-- handle Apex error -->
       </template>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

LWC js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getUncategorizedDocuments from '@Salesforce/apex/OnboardingReviewDocController1.getUncategorizedDocuments';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

// columns
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Onboarding Application Document Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
    }, {
        label: 'Document Type',
        fieldName: 'Document_Type__c',
        type: 'text',
        editable: true
    }, {
        label: 'First/Last/DOB',
        fieldName: 'First_Last_DOB__c',
        type: 'date',
    }, {
        label: 'Onboarding Application Owner',
        fieldName: 'Onboarding_Application_Owner__c',
        type: 'text',
    },{
        label: 'UBO ID',
        fieldName: 'UBO_ID__c',
        type: 'text',
    }, {
        label: 'S3 Link',
        fieldName: 'S3_link__c',
        type: 'url',
    }, {
        label: 'Document Status',
        fieldName: 'Document_Status__c',
        type: 'text',
    },
   
];

export default class OnboardingFileLabelRemediation extends LightningElement {
    error;
    columns = columns;

    @wire(getUncategorizedDocuments)
    onbAppDocs;
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class OnboardingReviewDocController1 {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<onb_Onboarding_Application_Document__c> getUncategorizedDocuments() {
        return [SELECT Document_Type__c,First_Last_DOB__c,Id,Name,Onboarding_Application_Owner_Name__c,S3_link__c,UBO_ID__c,Verification_Status__c 
                FROM onb_Onboarding_Application_Document__c 
                WHERE Document_Type__c != NULL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LWC, and JavaScript in general, is case sensitive. Your typo appears to be:

```
import getUncategorizedDocuments from '@Salesforce/apex/OnboardingReviewDocController1.getUncategorizedDocuments';
```

Because it should be:

```
import getUncategorizedDocuments from '@salesforce/apex/OnboardingReviewDocController1.getUncategorizedDocuments';
                                   //   ^ must be lowercase s.
```

Always pay attention to the documentation and examples closely, because even a single inverted cased letter can cause compile or runtime errors.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much for pointing out the obvious. Will pay closer attention to detail next time :)